# X509 certificate works locally but not as service

Tags: c#, ssl, windows-services, x509certificate

I have a C# program that loads a `PFX` certificate file and uses it to communicate with a web server.  I can run the program by double clicking on it and the certificate is loaded and I can communicate with the web server without a problem.

However, when I recompile my program as a Windows Service (which means uncommenting two lines and recompiling) and trigger a request to the web server I got the error message as `"The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."`

Only two lines of code change when I recompile as a service and these lines have nothing to do with the certificate or the request to the web server.  Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Comment: How do you load the certificate file? With a relative or absolute path? If the latter is the case, how do you construct it?

Comment: Hi Matten.  I load the certificate from an absolute path, which at the moment is a hard coded string: "X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate("C:\cert.pfx", "password1");"

Comment: Does the service has the right to access this file?